# For what constant $c$ does Struve function $\mathbf{H}_1(x) = c$ have infinitely many roots?

Tags: roots, special-functions, bessel-functions, constants

**I. Sine integral**

We start with the plot of the sine integral $\rm{Si}(x)$,

[image]

The median point $1.57$ in fact is $\frac{\pi}2 \approx 1.5708$, so the equation $\rm{Si}(x) = \frac{\pi}2$ has infinitely many zeros.

**II. Struve function**

The [Struve function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html) $\mathbf{H}_1(x)$ has the plot,

[image]

**Q:** What is the exact value of $c \approx 0.64$ such that $\mathbf{H}_1(x) = c$ has infinitely many zeros? (I don't think it is $\frac{\pi}5\approx 0.628$.)

Comment: Your $\frac \pi 5$ was quite good since $\pi^2 \sim 10$. Tomorrow, I shall add an asymptotics to my answer. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } \, \mathbf{H}_1(x)=\frac 2 \pi \approx 0.63662$$

Have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StruveFunction.html) for a good approximation of $ \mathbf{H}_1(x)$.

**Edit**

A simple asymptotics of the function for large $x$ is

$$\mathbf{H}_1(x)\sim\frac 2 \pi-\frac{(8 x-3) \sin (x)+(8 x+3) \cos (x) } {8\sqrt\pi \,x^{\frac 3 2}}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 10 & 0.88535469 & 0.89183249 \\
 20 & 0.47115765 & 0.47268818 \\
 30 & 0.72103373 & 0.72175038 \\
 40 & 0.63082698 & 0.63122341 \\
 50 & 0.57982665 & 0.58007845 \\
 60 & 0.72848642 & 0.72866607 \\
 70 & 0.54177739 & 0.54190496 \\
 80 & 0.70601440 & 0.70611511 \\
 90 & 0.61043293 & 0.61051110 \\
 100 & 0.61624769 & 0.61631110 \\
 200 & 0.65192155 & 0.65193751 \\
 300 & 0.66986528 & 0.66987239 \\
 400 & 0.67543349 & 0.67543750 \\
 500 & 0.67073084 & 0.67073340 \\
 600 & 0.65862759 & 0.65862936 \\
 700 & 0.64292911 & 0.64293041 \\
 800 & 0.62773906 & 0.62774005 \\
 900 & 0.61661621 & 0.61661699 \\
 1000 & 0.61183544 & 0.61183608
\end{array}
\right)$$

This approximation shows that, for large $x$, the successive solutions $x_k$ of equation
$$\mathbf{H}_1(x)=\frac 2 \pi$$ are "almost"
$$x_{k+1}\sim x_k + \pi$$ Computing, for the range of your plot, a few roots rigorously and using the approximation
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{exact}  & \text{approximation} \\
 150.008983620 & 150.008549357 \\
 153.149772398 & 153.150193291 \\
 156.292243506 & 156.291835163 \\
 159.433078832 & 159.433475096 \\
 162.575498103 & 162.575113201 \\
 165.716375636 & 165.716749583 \\
 168.858747959 & 168.858384338 \\
 171.999663906 & 172.000017555 \\
 175.141993547 & 175.141649317 \\
 178.282944578 & 178.283279700 \\
 181.425235281 & 181.424908777 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Dang, it was just $c = \frac{2}{\pi}$? I thought it would be some other constant, but $\pi$ really is ubiquitous.